# What is the metal box the dishwasher parts are in called? Dishwasher housing/body/case?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, technical

I'm translating a technical text and can't decide about wording. How do you call a metal box the dishwasher parts are in? The variants are "housing"/"body"/"case"/"frame". Not the "cabinet" - I don't need a wooden box for in-built models. Housing is about computers, isn't it? So what is the correct word? Thanks.

Comment: Generally a dishwasher intended to be installed "built-in" will have a "frame".

Comment: What if it is free standing?

Comment: There isn't really a "recognised" term, but *body* or *case* would likely be correctly understood. I'd avoid *housing* as it can be used for the wooden cabinets for built-in appliances, such as e.g. on [diy-kitchens](https://www.diy-kitchens.com/kitchen-units/tall/appliance-housing/).

Comment: ...a free-standing dishwasher? Could you maybe post a photo in your question?

Comment: *Cabinet* does not mean wood. (However, it also doesn't mean what you're talking about here.)

Comment: Free-standing is not the question that was asked.

Comment: @HotLicks Does such an animal even exist? I have installed a couple, and all were mounted on quadrilateral frames covered in insulating material. I can't imagine what a free-standing looks like. How the hell would you hook it up? To the sink? Sounds like something created by the Soviet Workers Paradise.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yeah, you hook it up to the sink.  My MIL had one.

Comment: Cascabel There certainly are free-standing dishwashers, (in the UK and Europe at least) They look much the same as other free-standing white goods, particularly washing macines and tumble driers (although they don't have round glass porthole doors). The only difference between the built-in and freestanding ones is that the freestanding ones have a pressed steel casing which the built-in ones do not.

Comment: Do you mean the stainless steel inner compartment or the outer shell?  "The dishwasher parts" isn't very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Appliances have a **chassis**.

> Able to be found in high or low temperature models, the Electronic
>   Series from Jet-Tech consists of an especially efficient line of
>   products. The SmartSelf diagnostics alerts help you keep track of
>   maintenance throughout the years, and the OneGo LED Control System
>   features soft-touch buttons and allows you to choose between three
>   different cycle-types. Machines from the Electronic Series aren’t only
>   full of useful properties; dishwasher models from this line have
>   **stainless steel chassis components** and wash tank for additional longevity.

https://www.compactappliance.com/jet-tech/

The chassis of an appliance may be considered to include the body panels or not. Body and housing are perfectly fine also. It really depends on your audience. For the home owner, I might go with housing. For high end commercial gear, I would make the distinction between chassis and body.

Answer (score 1):

Going with one of the words you already propose, I would call it the dishwasher [**frame**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frame):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **4 a** : a machine built upon or within a framework
> // a spinning *frame*
> **b** : an open case or structure made for admitting, enclosing, or supporting something
> // a window *frame*

Note that a frame can be made of any material.

---

[**Housing**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/housing) might also work, but I'm used it it being used in a different context. (One involving habitation or smaller items.)

Answer (score 0):

I call it cladding.  Typically laid over a frame.

M-W gives:

> [cladding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cladding)
>
> something that covers or overlays
>
> specifically :
> metal coating bonded
> to a metal core

Comment: Hi Kris, it's encouraged to include a source and examples of the usage in context here. I got you started with a definition and hope you'll [edit] to elaborate, and welcome!  Do take a moment to [tour] and see the [help].

Answer (score -1):

If the picture below is what you are asking about, then it is called the dishwasher tub. You can Google this to get confirmation about its widespread use. Here is one example: [SEARS Parts Direct](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/W10413848/0022/665.html?origin=legacy&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=W10413848&sid=SPDxGPROD&k_clickID=ec11ea89-5945-4920-895d-9dd42841b3a0&msclkid=a36cff0cf1e11ec50e59a3502873ff70).

While some dishwashers are stand-alone and have an exterior cabinet that encloses the tub, the largest part of a cabinet-installed dishwasher would be the tub, with no structural enclosure outside of it.

[image: A Dishwasher Tub]

You can find more information about English terms for dishwasher parts by searching "dishwasher parts" and looking at the pictures from that search, along with their corresponding links for more details. That should lead you down a path that helps you out.